# HTML5 re-open android keyboard doesn't trigger focus event

Tags: android, html

I'm developing a HTML5 chat application, and I need to scroll down the message's area each time the keyboard is open. For that I'm listenig to the focus event on the textbox input.

But, in Android you can hide the keyboard without losing focus by pressing the arrow down button next to the home button (at least in 4.2), if you press again in the textbox input it will re-open the keyboard without triggering the "focus" event.

Is there any workaround to this?

Thanks.